# Get client time on Apache server

Tags: command-line-interface, apache2, timestamp

I actually have two questions:

1) The timestamp in Apache error.log file is client's time or the server's?

2) If I connect to the server via command line and execute the command `HEAD / HTTP/1.0`, what does the `client-date` produced among others represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache error.log shows the server's time when the error occured.

Apache access.log shows the server's time when the response has been completely produced.

If your web application produces a `client-date` response header, the content is entirely up to that app. Apache is not concerned.